# Missed Iron Key

Tags: shadowrun

Whenever I first arrived at Daley Station, I was jumped by 2 baddies. One tried to initiate a conversation with me, but I accidentally exited. Apparently one of them drops an iron key used to access the Rust Stilettos hideout, but I also missed that. Any way to get around needing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the Iron Key goes into your inventory, even if you do not pick it up.